# Prove that $\int _0^{\infty }\frac{xe^{-x^2}}{x+2}dx\:$ converges without finding the value or using dirichlet test

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How can i prove that **$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{xe^{-x^2}}{x+2}dx\:$** coverges without finding the value or using dirichlet test ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you know $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}$ converges, then you can use the fact that $\frac{x}{x+2} < 1$ and bound it above by a convergent function.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{x}{x+2}<1, \qquad\forall x\geq0
$$
so that 
$$
\frac{x}{x+2}e^{-x^2}<e^{-x^2}, \qquad\forall x\geq0
$$
and finally
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x+2}e^{-x^2}dx<\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx
$$
The right-hand side is an integral that is known to be convergent.

Comment: Can you explain by words a little bit please :) ?

Comment: Edited, is it clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\dfrac{x}{x+2}<1$ when $x\geq 0$ we have
$$f(x)=\dfrac{xe^{-x^2}}{x+2}<e^{-x^2}$$
for such $x$. Now $e^{-x^2}\leq e^{-x}$ if $x\geq 1$ hence
$$0\leq f(x)\leq e^{-x}$$
if $x\geq 1$. The integral $\int_1^{\infty} e^{-x}dx$ is convergent, hence $\int_1^{\infty} f(x)dx$ too. Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ the integral over $[0,\infty[$ converges too.